# Stabilize massive heat sink before shipping PC

Tags: heatsink

### Preface

I'm shipping a friend's PC from Delaware to Hawaii. Last time this PC made this journey, the heat sink fell off and damaged the video card. This one of those massive gaming PC heat sinks that weigh a ton.

This time, we removed the video card and shipped separately.

I'd prefer not to remove the heat sink since my friend is not comfortable with applying thermal paste and reattaching it to the CPU.

### Question

Is there anyway I could stabilize the heat sink in the case to prevent it from breaking off of the retaining plastic while in transit?

### My solution based on feedback.

I ended up detaching the heatsink. I wrapped it in anti-static bubble wrap, put it inside the case, then filled the case with bubble wrap. It seemed to be pretty secure. When it got to Hawaii, he was able to put it back on without issue.

Comment: cram the case full of packing peanuts?

Comment: Question doesn't seem to be in SU scope. Maybe try lifehacks.SE?

Comment: @FrankThomas Not sure what packing peanuts you are using but I usually find foam to be incredibly STATIC!

Comment: whats a little shorted circuitry between friends, right?

Comment: @MonkeyZeus They sell [anti-static foam](http://www.amazon.com/3-1-Pink-Static-Packing-Peanuts/dp/B000SL2ELE) for shipping electronics.

Comment: If the heatsink is properly fastened on, and the whole case is boxed properly with padding, then it won't come off.

Comment: @psusi - wrong, wrong & wrong - if the case is knocked hard enough, the weight of the heat sink will simply smash it off the PCB.

Comment: @Tetsujin, you're supposed to pad it enough so that if the box takes a reasonable knock, it won't shock the computer that much.  Enough force to dislodge a properly fastened heatsink is enough to damage the hard disk.

Comment: @psusi - stock heatsink, sure... big old Zalman will break the mobo long before anything bothers the HD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heat sinks should *not* be shipped attached to the processor, as you already found out.

The best thing to do is to ship it unattached, as not to cause any damage.  If he doesnt feel comfortable putting it on, he should find someone locally who can.  Paying someone else to do it should only be a few dollars, as it is 5 minutes of work.

However, if you still plan on shipping it attached try this: Cut a small peice of cardboard to cover the heat sink and then put a very thick block of foam on it and then stretch tape over the foam  to the outside of the computer case itself.  That should put enough pressure on the heat sink to keep it in place, yet still be easy to remove.  The cardboard will prevent the foam from getting in the heat sink and fan and allow for the foam to apply even pressure.

Comment: I cannot advise more that shipping a computer with a non-stock cooling solution is a extremly bad idea but must admit the solution with the foam would work.

Comment: Per your advice, I ended up detaching the heatsink. I wrapped it in anti-static bubble wrap, put it inside the case, then filled the case with bubble wrap. It seemed to be pretty secure. We'll see what happens when it gets to Hawaii.

Answer (score 0):

1) You could try Instapak Quick.  Here is an [InstaPak Foam Computer Packaging Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tB54ZZ9bqa4).  While not cheap, [you can buy it at Uline](http://www.uline.com/BL_7701/Instapak-Quickreg).  I would be concerned about static, so be sure to static proof everything.

2) Personally, I would switch to a closed loop liquid cooling solution, like [NZXT Kraken](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16835146042), as there is less weight on the motherboard.

**Edit:**  Flashpac might be a good alternative to Instapak, as it does not require a heater.  [Check out this video of Flashpac](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t3R5hIEIPtk).

Answer (score 0):

If it's one of those really heavy copper fin structures, wobbling over a stock CPU install with a supposedly-secure added back-frame… then stabilising only the top will not prevent it punching though the mobo in transit. You would also need to under-pack the cooler **and** the mobo itself to prevent punch-though.

Comment: What do you mean by punch through? Like the heat sink itself will punch a hole in the motherboard PCB?

Comment: Yes, it's possible if you've a 2KG off-balance weight on a PCB, punch-through or tear-off. I've a big Zalman on one machine; the instructions said to remove it before shipping to prevent just that.